# Rails association condition with arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a problem with this association.

before:

```
has_many  :membership, class_name: 'Profile', conditions: "profiles.role != 'owner'"
```

Currently the attribute "role" isnt an string anymore and now is an array so I need to change that condition that results in records whose "role" is ['owner'] (not 'owner') but I can not us an array to the match.

wanted:

```
has_many  :memberships, class_name: 'Profile', conditions: "profiles.role != ['owner']"
```

Profile model

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :role

  serialize :role, Array
  belongs_to :account

  def roles?(role)
    role.include?(role)
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you please provide role definition in Profile model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. The correct query is:

```
`profiles`.`role` NOT LIKE '%owner%'
```

Using arel:

```
Profile.arel_table[:role].does_not_match('%owner%').to_sql
```

result:

```
profiles`.`role` NOT LIKE '%owner%
```

I guess that even with column type "string" serialized, this is still "string" to sql for searching. But, again, is an assumption.

Answer (score 1):

how does role column look in database? is it a string?

If its a varchar column then the below code should work.

```
has_many  :memberships, class_name: 'Profile', conditions: "profiles.role not in ('owner')"
```

Comment: your advice didn't work.. i don't know why, i tried it before and now again, but it still returns all profiles.

An owner cant be anything else so that is how a owner profile looks like
`<Profile account_id: 243, id: 257, role: ["owner"] >`

a regular profile looks like
`<Profile account_id: 243, id: 257, role: ["author", "moderator"] >`

role column isstring type and I serialized it on my profile model

`serialize :role, Array`

Comment: Could you paste the result of "select * from profiles limit 1" ?